# JMS client selector not working

Tags: java, jms

I am getting the below jms message.I built a simple main to receive the JMS messages but the problem I am unable to filter the JMS received by using the "selector".

```
Message sent format
<eventmsg>
<event ucaname="UCA_Message" processApp="PDWEB">Message</event>
<parameters>
<parameter>
<key>sessionKey</key>
<value>123123</value>
</parameter>
</parameters>
</eventmsg>



import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.QueueConnection;
import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.QueueReceiver;
import javax.jms.QueueSession;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class JMSClient
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        QueueSession qs = null;
        QueueConnection qc = null;
        QueueReceiver queueReceiver = null;

        try
        {
            String JNDI_URL = "Myserver-server:2929";
            // The QUEUE_NAME is the name of the queue that receives the JMS message
            String QUEUE_NAME = "jms/eventqueue";
            // USER and PASS to connect to the server, this can be removed by disabling security in
            // the bus
            String USER = "admin12";
            String PASSWORD = "admin12";

            String jndiUrl = "corbaname:iiop:" + JNDI_URL;
            String initialContextFactory = "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory";
            String qcfName = "javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory";
            String queueName = QUEUE_NAME;

            // Kept as Hashtable, as the InitialContext constructor does not accept HashMap.
            Hashtable<String, String> props = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, initialContextFactory);
            props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, jndiUrl);
            Context ctx = new InitialContext(props);

            // Lookup JMS queue
            Queue errorQ = (Queue) ctx.lookup(queueName);
            // Lookup QueueConnectionFactory and create QueueSession
            QueueConnectionFactory qcf = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(qcfName);
            // Creates the connection to the server using the admin and password set
            qc = qcf.createQueueConnection(USER, PASSWORD);
            qs = qc.createQueueSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            qc.start();
            String selector = "sessionKey = '123123'";

            queueReceiver = qs.createReceiver(errorQ,selector);
            Message inMessage = queueReceiver.receive();

            String replyString = ((TextMessage) inMessage).getText();
            System.out.println(replyString);
        }

        catch (JMSException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NamingException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                queueReceiver.close();
                qs.close();
                qc.close();
            }
            catch (JMSException e)
            {
                // log.error("Exception occured while Releasing JMS connection", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is sessionKey?  Is that a custom field or something?

Comment: yes it is a custom field

Answer (score 1):

Extracted from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JMS4.html)

```
 Message Selectors
```

If your messaging application needs to filter the messages it receives, you can use a JMS API message selector, which allows a message consumer to specify the messages it is interested in. Message selectors assign the work of filtering messages to the JMS provider rather than to the application. For an example of an application that uses a message selector, see A J2EE Application That Uses the JMS API with a Session Bean.

A message selector is a String that contains an expression. The syntax of the expression is based on a subset of the SQL92 conditional expression syntax.

```
  The message selector in the example selects any message that has a NewsType property   that is set to the value 'Sports' or 'Opinion':

NewsType = 'Sports' OR NewsType = 'Opinion'
```

The createConsumer and createDurableSubscriber methods allow you to specify a message selector as an argument when you create a message consumer.

```
 The message consumer then receives only messages whose headers and properties match the selector. (See Message Headers, and Message Properties.) A message selector cannot select messages on the basis of the content of the message body.
```

Answer (score 1):

If sessionKey is set as a number, can you try the selector without quotes?  i.e. **sessionKey = 12345**

Comment: This seems much more likely to be the cause of problem, than the first answer.